# Unable to resolve path to module 'ipfs-core'

Tags: reactjs, eslint, vite, ipfs

Am importing IPFS library to my React+Vite typescript project like this:
`import * as IPFS from "ipfs-core";`
but am encountering error `Unable to resolve path to module 'ipfs-core'.`
While ipfs-core is in node-modules, it is also in package.json. I cannot find solution how to get this to working.

```
 npm ls ipfs-core
viteproject@0.0.1 /home/rp/development/
└── ipfs-core@0.18.0
```

**This is my eslintrc.json:**

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "es6": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "prettier",
    "react-app",
    "plugin:import/recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
  ],
  "globals": {
    "Atomics": "readonly",
    "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
  },
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["react", "react-hooks", "prettier", "@typescript-eslint"],
  "rules": {
    "prefer-spread": "off",
    "no-empty-pattern": "off",
    "prettier/prettier": "error",
    "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error",
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface": "off"
  },
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "version": "18.2"
    },
    "import/parsers": {
      "@typescript-eslint/parser": [".ts", ".tsx"]
    },
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "paths": ["src", "node_modules"],
        "extensions": [
          ".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**this is my vite.config.json:**

```
import path from "path";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import eslint from "vite-plugin-eslint";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import { NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin } from "@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill";

const resolveFixup = {
  name: "resolve-fixup",
  setup(build) {
    build.onResolve({ filter: /react-virtualized/ }, async (args) => {
      return {
        path: path.resolve("./node_modules/react-virtualized/dist/umd/react-virtualized.js"),
      };
    });
  },
};

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), eslint()],
  define: {
    global: "globalThis",
  },
  server: {
    // https: true,
    port: 3000,
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      path: "path-browserify",
      stream: "stream-browserify",
      crypto: "crypto-browserify",
    },
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    esbuildOptions: {
      // Node.js global to browser globalThis
      define: {
        global: "globalThis",
      },
      // Enable esbuild polyfill plugins
      plugins: [
        resolveFixup,
        NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin({
          buffer: true,
        }),
      ],
    },
  },
});
```

**this is my tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

i tried importing it in different ways, nothing worked. I tried to ignore error but i got this error in console:
`react-dom.development.js:26923 Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'process' has already been declared (at ipfs-core.js?v=437ba4ef:57614:1)`